# How to display two tables in one crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

My invoice can have many Items (*each Item has : Description, Quantity, Unit price and Price...classic !*) but the invoice can also have many Taxes (*from 0 to 5 taxes, in the example I'm showing, this invoice has 3 taxes : 17%, 4% and 10%, while other invoices can have no Taxes at all*)

Here is my GUI (you can see in red the items and in blue the taxes :
[image: My application GUI]

Here is the Dataset I'm using :
[image: Dataset]

**Here is the Template of the report i want to make** :
[image: Report i need to make]

I googled for result and i found an example [LINK => SOLUTION N°2](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/772444/How-do-I-display-two-different-query-results-in-tw) where they suggest that you create the second table (Taxes) in different report and than **Insert** it in the first report (Items) as **SubReport** , my problem is that i need to insert the **Total No Taxes => 12 900.00** before i add the Taxes table...! so i didn't know **in which Section of the Item's report i need to insert the Taxes Report** !

1. I want to know if it is possible to create a such report ?
2. Is the solution I'm following the right way to do it ?
3. If not or if there is a better way to do it please show me ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you will add a summary field in the report footer to show the sum of "Price" as "TOTAL NO TAXES" then add sub-report in the same section (i.e. report footer) that displays the "TaxesDataTable" data.

Answer (score 0):

Sub report approach is correct. Follow the process.

Calculate all data in main report then pass the summary to sub report and place the sub report in a section that comes after the data displayed in main report, best would be in report footer.
Calculate in sub report and display both